# There is no single-valued analytic function which tends to $0$ or $\infty$ like a fractional power of $|z-a|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis* page 128:

> For a more detailed discussion of isolated singularities, we consider the conditions (1) $\lim_{z\to a}|z-a|^\alpha|f(z)|=0$, (2) $\lim_{z\to a}|z-a|^\alpha|f(z)|=\infty$, for real values of $\alpha$. If (1) hold for a certain $\alpha$, then it holds for all larger $\alpha$, and hence for some integer $m$. Then $(z-a)^mf(z)$ has a removable singularity and vanishes for $z=a$. Either $f(z)$ is identically zero, in which case (1) holds for all $\alpha$, or $(z-a)^mf(z)$ has a zero of finite order $k$. In the latter case it follows at once that (1) holds for all $\alpha>h=m-k$, while (2) holds for all $\alpha<h$. Assume now that (2) holds for some $\alpha$; then it holds for all smaller $\alpha$, and hence for some integer $n$. The function $(z-a)^nf(z)$ has a pole of finite order $l$, and setting $h=n+l$ we find again that (1) holds for $\alpha>h$ and (2) for $\alpha<h$. The discussion shows that there are three possibilities: (i) condition (1) holds for all $\alpha$, and $f(z)$ vanishes identically; (ii) there exists an integer $h$ such that (1) holds for $\alpha>h$ and (2) for $\alpha<h$; (iii) neither (1) nor (2) holds for any $\alpha$.
>   Case (i) is uninteresting. In case (ii) $h$ may be called the *algebraic order* of $f(z)$ at $\alpha$. It is positive in case of a pole, negative in case of a zero, and zero if $f(z)$ is analytic but $\ne0$ at $a$. The remarkable thing is that the order is always an integer; there is no single-valued analytic function which tends to $0$ or $\infty$ like a fractional power of $|z-a|$.

Why is there no single-valued analytic function which tends to $0$ or $\infty$ like a fractional power of $|z-a|$?

Comment: Does Ahlfors specify exactly what tending to $0$ or $\infty$ "like" another function means explicitly? I could take a guess, but a bit more context would be good.

Comment: @TheoBendit I upload a new picture that includes a previous paragraph. I am not sure why he points out that.

Comment: The possible reason is that  a non-integer power is always multivalued in the domain containing its zero or pole.